Intuition behind construction for Induced Representations.
I'm studying representation theory. I've come across induced representations.
I really don't understand why the construction:
$$
W = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{[G:H]}g_iV
$$
as shown in this page produces a representation of $G$. How should I be thinking about this, and what exactly is the role of the cosets? Furthermore, are there any simple examples which make this construction clearer?

I do not know category theory or module theory so I would be grateful if the answers take more elementary approaches.


The basic idea is: you've got this representation $V$ of $H$, you want to somehow "upgrade" it into a representation $W$ of $G$. That involves saying something about how to multiply an element $g \in G$ by an element $v \in V$. How do you do that? In the induced representation you do it in the laziest possible way: you say it is some element $gv \in gV$, where $gV$ is a new copy of $V$ you've cooked up. You already know how $H$ acts so $gV$ is really a function of the coset of $g$. And that's where this construction comes from.
